# Intellij idea Debug: the application is running

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

IDE: idea2020
OS: windows10

I'm using idea, and I try to debug. When it goes to a certain step, next it steps into the jar of mina2.0. So I add the jar to the list: "Do not step into the classes".Then I debug again, and it always shows "The application is running" but it is not able to go to the next step.

Comment: Please check idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") for errors/warnings. Is it possible to share sample project example for investigation?

Answer (score 0):

Its because you should use the debugger options in the top-row to step to the next debug-point.
Not the regular "Resume application" button (The green one)

[image: debugger options]